# String in to list Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have a string, something like:

```
a = "[1, 2, 3]"
```

If there an easy way to convert it in to a list, without using .split(), join() etc.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ast.literal_eval()` it's safer than using `eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = literal_eval("[1, 2, 3]")

print(a)
```